# AlarmManager: Alarm is not fired unless i change date manually

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I have an alarm that should run everyday at 12AM (it is not a repeating alarm, i am setting it each time i need cz in some cases i dnt want it to run)

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(AlarmService.this, AlarmService.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

The weird thing is that if i change the date/time manually to 12Am of the next day the alarm is fired. But if i set time to 11:59Pm of today and wait till 12AM nothing happens and if the time/date was automatically set, it is also not firing at 12AM. Any idea why is that hapennning or how can i fix it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is some thing wrong in your code look at [this](http://blog.mikesir87.io/2013/04/android-creating-an-alarm-with-alarmmanager/) one i use it before it is perfect and it will improve your code.

Comment: well in my case, am restarting the alarm (my code above) inside the service class itself. Could this be causing the misbehavior ? @Omar Johari

Comment: @user1433460 u can use timer

Comment: look at this case it is relative to your problem or not ???
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807577/is-it-possible-to-have-a-alarmmanager-inside-a-service-class

Comment: I believe alarmManager is more suitable for my case. I want the service to run everyday at 12am and do a download; if it fails i reset the alarm to call the service in 1 hr to try again; and if it passes, i set the alarm to 12 am the next day. so please help me find best solution and thanks a lot

Comment: there is to way choose the one u feel it is better to u :

1- http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html

2-http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Comment: sry i cannot accept this as answer cz its not, but ill will upvote your posts as they were helpful.
my issue was that threads were behaving not as expected

Comment: so u still have a problem ??

Comment: no i fixed it...it was caused by a threading issue (async task didnt finish executing and i was trying to do smtn on the main UI assuming async task was done)

Comment: i'm happy for u, but like u see your solution and problem far a way from your question.So be be careful next time debug  before u ask :)